# Creation of prototype scoped component in Spring request handler method

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm writing a Spring app and learning Spring as I go. So far, whenever I find myself wanting to give something a reference to the `ApplicationContext`, it has meant I'm trying to do something the wrong way so I thought I'd ask before I did it.

I need to instantiate a prototype bean for each request:

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class ComplexThing {
    @Autowired SomeDependency a
    @Autowired SomeOtherDependency b
    public ComplexThing() { }
    // ... complex behaviour ...
}
```

So I tried this:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/")
class MyController {
    @GetMapping
    public String index (ComplexThing complexThing, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("thing", complexThing);
        return "index"
    }
}
```

And I expected Spring to inject a new `ComplexThing` for the request, just like it injected a `Model`. But then I found the correct interpretation of that is that the caller is going to send a ComplexThing in the request.

I thought there would be a way of injecting Beans into request handlers, but [I don't see one here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods).

So in this case am I *supposed to* make my Controller `ApplicationContextAware` and `getBean`?

Comment: *Why* do you want to use a prototype bean?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Because the object that I need to create to handle the request has a bunch of dependencies, and those have their own dependencies, etc. Isn't one of the main reasons for IoC to handle complex object creation?

Comment: Yes, and nothing you said bears on why it should be a _prototype_ rather than a _singleton_. What about this injected object varies from one request to another?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Fair enough. Well, the object will store some user data relating to the logged in user. Its a tree of business objects that lazily fetch and cache their data whenever my request handler needs some data. It's designed to be lazy because I am trying to be stateless - not persisting the user data in the session.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the `ObjectProvider` interface:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/")
class MyController {
    @Autowired 
    ObjectProvider<ComplexThing> complexThingProvider;
    @GetMapping
    public String index (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("thing", complexThingProvider.getObject());
        return "index"
    }
}
```

---

The other benefit of `ObjectProvider` is that was able to pass some arguments to the constructor, which meant I could mark some fields as `final`.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/")
class MyController {
    @Autowired 
    ObjectProvider<ComplexThing> complexThingProvider;
    @GetMapping
    public String index (String username, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("thing", complexThingProvider.getObject(username));
        return "index"
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class ComplexThing {
    @Autowired SomeDependency a
    @Autowired SomeOtherDependency b
    final String username;
    public ComplexThing(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    // ... complex behaviour ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your point is correct.  There is no way, the prototype scoped beans (actually every other bean type too) can be directly injected into a controller request handler.  We have only 4 options.

1. Get application Context in the caller, and pass the bean while calling the method. (But in this case, since this is a request handler, this way is not possible).
2. Making the controller class `ApplicationContextAware`, set the applicationContext object by overriding `setApplicationContext()` method and use it to get the bean's instance.
3. Create a private variable of the bean type and annotate it with `@Autowired`.
4. Create a private variable of the bean type and annotate it with `@Inject` (`@Autowired` and `@Inject` have the same functionality.  But `@Autowired` is spring specific).